# AWS clone now routes not working?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, amazon-web-services

So my site was getting pretty slammed so I made an AIM image of the server, waited for it to finish and spun up a new server. Change security groups and git pulled to make sure the servers were up to date. Now for whatever reason the homepage loads fine but all other pages give me this error.
Not Found

The requested URL /about was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon) Server at xx.xxx.xx.xxx Port 80

Any idea what could be going on? as I said the homepage is working, Laravel install and all.

Comment: Are you using mod_rewrite? If so and you use a .htaccess file to configure it can you check to ensure the file exists, is accessible by the web server software and has the right configuration?

Comment: Not using htaccess anywhere. I believe Laravel uses mod_rewrite but a full clone should have handled any of that config.

Comment: How is mod_rewrite configured then and how did you clone the image?

Comment: Using AWS create image selected a new size and hit launch. I have done this before without any issue.

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: It ended up being an IP conflict with another server had up. thanks for helping though!